# Installing .NET Framework 2.0 on Windows 7

Tags: .net, frameworks

I have an existing program that needs .NET Framework 2.0 on a 32-bit Windows 7 machine. A Google search suggested installing .NET Framework 3.5, which includes .NET Framework 2.0.  However, Microsoft does not seem to offer .NET Framework 3.5 as a download. I already have .NET Framework 3.51 on this machine, but it does not seem to support .NET Framework 2.0. I tried to install the .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 1, but it said that installation wasn't supported under Vista. Does anyone know a work-around?

Comment: "it does not seem to support .NET Framework 2.0"? In which way?

Answer (score 0):

I found on MS site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-7
It states “The .NET Framework 3.5 is included with Windows 7. The .NET Framework 3.5 supports apps built for .NET Framework 1.0 through 3.5.”

I think if you ran an update over the years it pushes you automatically to 3.5.1, that is what mine is at.

I did find a Microsoft .NET Framework Version 2.0 Redistributable Package (x64) at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6523

I also found a .Net 2.0 (86) SDK on MS website.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19988

I could not find a link on MS site for x86 redistributable, but I did find one setting on CNET!!!!
https://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-NET-Framework-Redistributable-Package-x86/3000-10250_4-10726028.html